# How can I read the EXIF data from an image taken with an Apple iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, exif

How can I read the EXIF data from an image taken with an **Apple iPhone** using C#?

I need the GPS related data.

PS: I know how to read EXIF except image taken with an **Apple iPhone**

Comment: Have you solve this issue? I have the same problem. Apple does not save in PropertyTagGpsLatitude=0x0002 and PropertyTagGpsLongitude=0x0004 :(

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you take a look at the [exiflibrary](http://code.google.com/p/exiflibrary/) project on Google Code and its associated [ExifLibrary for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExifLibrary.aspx) article on Code Project.

It supports over 150 known EXIF tags including 32 GPS related ones. Getting the latitude and longitude is as easy as:

```
var exif = ExifFile.Read(fileName);
Console.WriteLine(exif.Properties[ExifTag.GPSLatitude]);
Console.WriteLine(exif.Properties[ExifTag.GPSLongitude]);
```

It even has a neat little demo application with an interactive visualization of the binary data:
[image: ExifLibrary demo]

Comment: I try the demo, but it can not read the EXIF of an image taken with an "Apple iPhone"

Comment: I think the demo from Code Project is an older version. You should try compiling the demo app against the latest release (v0.9) from Google Code.

Comment: v0.9 can not extract the GPS EXIF data from IPhone's image

Answer (score 3):

The *MetadataExtractor* library has been available for Java since 2002 and is now fully supported for .NET. It supports Exif GPS data from JPEG files, along with a tonne of other metadata types and file types.

Here are examples of the output from an [iPhone 4](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-images/blob/master/jpg/metadata/apple%20iphone%204.jpg.txt#L51), [iPhone 5](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-images/blob/master/jpg/metadata/apple%20iphone%205.jpg.txt#L47) and an [iPhone 6](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-images/blob/master/jpg/metadata/apple%20iphone%206.jpg.txt#L56).

It's available via NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package MetadataExtractor
```

Then, to access the GPS location, use the following code:

```
var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(jpegFilePath);

var gps = directories.OfType<GpsDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();

var location = gps?.GetGeoLocation();

if (location != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Lat {0} Lng {1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
```

Or to print out every single discovered value:

```
var lines = from directory in directories
            from tag in directory.Tags
            select $"{directory.Name}: {tag.TagName} = {tag.Description}";

foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you load an image using:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(imageName);
```

The EXIF values are read into the `PropertyItems` array on the image.

I found some code for interpreting these tags as EXIF data. I can't remember where I got it from now but I've found a copy [here](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/Code/Libraries/Graphics/Reading_EXIF_Tags_from_JPG_Files/EXIF_Tags.asp). I don't think that the code as it stands reads the geolocation codes, but [this page](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) claims to have a list of all EXIF tags, so you could extend this code.

Tag id `0x8825` is the GPSInfo. The GPS tags are enumerated on [this page](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html)