# C# library to extract Lens Make/Model from EXIF data in JPG images

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, exif

I need to extract the following pieces of information from any jpg that is uploaded to a website:

- Aperture
- Focal Length
- ISO Setting
- Camera Make/Model
- **Lens Make/Model**

I'm not worried about all of the other EXIF data that is contained within images. I have used an old library in the past which has got the first 4 items in that list without a problem, but I've not located one yet that can get the Lens Make & Model.

Does anyone know of a library that I can use within my ASP.NET MVC C# project that handles all of the above?

Comment: Does .Net libraries detail this information using System.Drawing.Image.PropertyItems?

Comment: this could be a good starting point,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169444/how-can-i-read-the-exif-data-from-an-image-taken-with-an-apple-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now located a C# wrapper for [EXIFTOOL by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), which extracts all the information I need (and then some!). The C# wrapper, written by Willem Semmelink is [here](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ExifToolWrapper_cs.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Exiftool is amazing. However if you want a simple, native C# solution, try my [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).